# Python, reading/writing from a file formatting

Tags: python

Solved by Nick Fegley below:

> cache.append('\ntest1') Should add the \n to just the last line.

Bit of a specific problem. I have a text file that contains the following

```html
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
11111
22222
33333
```

I then have a python script

```html
cache = []

f = open('testFile.txt', 'r')
cache = list(f)
f.close()
print(len(cache))
cache.append('test1')

print(len(cache))
f = open('testFile.txt', 'w')

for id in cache:
 f.write(id)

f.close()
```

Which should read each line of the text file, store it into a single element in the cache list, add "test1" into cache, wipe the file, and then write every element from cache into the file again, including the newly added "test1" on its own line.

However, instead of printing on a new line, it adds "test1" right after "33333". (so the last line reads "33333test1")

I tried adding a "\n" before/after the id in the f.write(id) loop, however that adds a whole new line to each entry and mucks up the formatting, and causing the next run to have blank line elements.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cache.append('\ntest1')` Should add the `\n` to just the last line.

Comment: @Odd822 if you feel that this is the right answer, you should accept it